# Alarmmanager when i reboot how can i remaining time

Tags: android

My code `am.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME,7*AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pi);`
when I reboot AlarmManager will be cancel. How can I do in reboot broadcastreceiver, I want to count remaining time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want remaining time then save the Time you set to trigger your alarm in cache

```
  long timeOfTrigger =  System.getCurrentcurrentTimeMillis() + 7 * AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY;

  //use RTC instead of ELAPSED_REALTIME
  //RTC calculates absolute time while 
  //ELAPSED_REALTIME calculates time that has passed since the android system boot.
  am.set(AlarmManager.RTC,timeOfTrigger, pi);
  Context context = getActivity();
  SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
  editor.putLong("TimeWhenAlarmStarts", timeOfTrigger );
  editor.commit();
```

This will save the value of the trigger time in cache. Then at any time (even if you have rebooted the app or the phone) you can find the remaining time just by

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 long timeOfTrigger = sharedPref.getLong("TimeWhenAlarmStarts" , defaultValue ); 
 long remainingtime = timeOfTrigger - System.getCurrentTimeInMillis();
 // the default value can be anything and is used if the SharedPreferences where empty
```

Comment: if i change android time RTC will be change?

Comment: Wait RTC calculates time using [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) so even if you change your timezone the RTC won't be affected, so the above code should work fine.

Comment: thanks i found this way to resloved problem.I use jude phone AUTO_TIME,when he change phone time this app will unable to open